connect(): "Connection refused" and I have no idea why
I'd still consider myself a C beginner, I'm trying to learn socket programming and honestly I'm kind of struggling.
I'm trying to create a server that manages a char room that any number of clients can connect to and chat with all others.
Here comes lots of code:
server.c
/* Server that manages a chatroom */

// Necessary includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// Custom header files includes
#include "func/func.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // ~~~~~~~~~~ Argument validation - START ~~~~~~~~~~
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    if (argc == 1) {
        printusage();
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc > 3) {
        printf("Too many arguments\n");
        printusage();
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Not enough arguments\n");
        printusage();
        return 1;
    }

    int status = is_addr(argv[1]);
    if (status != 1) {
        switch (status) {
            case ELONG:
                printf("<addr> argument too long\n");
                break;
            case ECHAR:
                printf("<addr> argument contains invalid characters\n");
                break;
            case EINVALID:
                printf("<addr> argument is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("unknown error...\n");
                break;
        }
        return 1;

    }
    status = is_port(argv[2]);
    if (status != 1) {
        switch(status) {
            case ELONG:
                printf("<port> argument too long\n");
                break;
            case ECHAR:
                printf("<port> argument not a valid port number\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("unknown error...\n");
        }
        return 1;
    }
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~ Argument validation - END ~~~~~~~~~~~
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    status = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[2], &hints, &res);
    if (status != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo(): error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }
    printf("getaddrinfo(): Success!\n");

    char addrstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int iptest = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in *ipv4;
    struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6;
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "0") == 0) { // List of options
        printaddrs(res);
        printf("Select an address to bind to: ");
        char *id = strin(stdin);
        int count = 0;
        for (; res != NULL; res = res->ai_next) {
            if (strtol(id, NULL, 10) == count) {
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (res->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ipv4->sin_addr, addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
        } else if (res->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
            ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)res->ai_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &ipv6->sin6_addr, addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
        } else {
            printf("Invalid address family!\n");
            freeaddrinfo(res);
            return 1;
        }
        free(id);
    } else { // User entered a specific address
        strcpy(addrstr, argv[1]);
        int addrfamily = getaddrfamily(addrstr);
        if (addrfamily == AF_INET) {
            ipv4 = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
            printf("addrstr: %s\n", addrstr);
            inet_pton(AF_INET, addrstr, &ipv4->sin_addr);
            res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)ipv4;
            res->ai_addr->sa_family = AF_INET;
            res->ai_family = AF_INET;
            res->ai_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
            iptest = 4;
        } else if (addrfamily == AF_INET6) {
            ipv6 = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));;
            inet_pton(AF_INET6, addrstr, &ipv6->sin6_addr);
            res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)ipv6;
            res->ai_addr->sa_family = AF_INET6;
            res->ai_family = AF_INET6;
            res->ai_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);
            iptest = 6;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid address family!\n");
            freeaddrinfo(res);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
    printf("Server address: %s\n", addrstr);
    printf("Server port: %s\n", argv[2]);

    int serverfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (serverfd == -1) {
        printf("socket(): error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        terminate(res, ipv4, ipv6, iptest);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("socket(): Success!\n");

    if (bind(serverfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        printf("bind(): error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        terminate(res, ipv4, ipv6, iptest);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("bind(): Success!\n");

    if (listen(serverfd, 16) == -1) {
        printf("listen(): error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        terminate(res, ipv4, ipv6, iptest);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Server listening on port %s...\n", argv[2]);

    int *clientfds;     // array of connected clients (file descriptors)
    pthread_t accept_t; // thread for accepting new connections
    pthread_t *read_t;  // array of threads for reading from existing connections
    pthread_t *write_t; // array of threads for writing to existing connections
    serverinfo server = {serverfd, NULL, 0};

    pthread_create(&accept_t, NULL, handle_new, (void *)&server);

    pthread_join(accept_t, NULL);
    terminate(res, ipv4, ipv6, iptest);
    return 0;
}

client.c
/* Client to connect to server.c */

// Necessary includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "func/func.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;


    int status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2],&hints, &res);
    if (status != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo(): error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }
    printf("getaddrinfo(): Success!\n");

    int clientfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (clientfd == -1) {
        printf("socket(): error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        freeaddrinfo(res);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("socket(): Success!\n");
    if (connect(clientfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        printf("connect(): error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(clientfd);
        freeaddrinfo(res);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Connected to server!\n");
}

func.h (contains function declarations)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define ELONG -1 // addr is too long
#define ECHAR -2 // addr contains invalid characters
#define EINVALID -3 // addr is invalid for other reasons

typedef struct serverinfo {
    int si_serverfd; // file descriptor of the server
    int *si_clientfds; // array of connected clients (file descriptors)
    int si_size; // size of si_clientfds (number of connected clients))
} serverinfo;

// func/strin.c
char *strin(FILE *stream);

// func/validation.c
int is_digit(char c);
int is_ipv4(char *addr);
int is_ipv6(char *addr);
int is_addr(char *addr);
int is_port(char *port);
int getaddrfamily(char *addr);
void printusage();

// func/printaddrs.c
void printaddrs(struct addrinfo *res);

// func/terminate.c
void terminate(struct addrinfo *res, struct sockaddr_in *ipv4, struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6, int iptest);

// func/pthread.c
void *handle_new(void *si);

func/pthread.c
/* <pthread.h> related functions */
#include "func.h"

//
void *handle_new(void *si) {
    serverinfo *server = (serverinfo *)si;
    printf("Waiting for connection...\n");
    int tempfd = accept(server->si_serverfd, NULL, NULL);
    if (tempfd == -1)
        printf("accept_t: accept(): error\n");
    printf("New connection!\n");
    server->si_size++;
    server->si_clientfds = realloc(server->si_clientfds, server->si_size * sizeof(int));
    return NULL;
}

func/printaddrs.c
#include "func.h"

void printaddrs(struct addrinfo *res) {
    struct sockaddr_in *ipv4;
    struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6;
    char addrstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int count = 0;
    char ipver[5];
    for (struct addrinfo *p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ipv4->sin_addr, addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
            strcpy(ipver, "IPv4");
            printf("%d|%s\t%s\n", count, ipver, addrstr);
        }else if (p->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
            ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &ipv6->sin6_addr, addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
            strcpy(ipver, "IPv6");
            printf("%d|%s\t%s\n", count, ipver, addrstr);
        }
        count++;
    }
}

func/validation.c
#include "func.h"

// Returns 1 if character c is a digit, otherwise returns 0
int is_digit(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '0' ... '9':
            return 1;
        case 'a' ... 'f':
            return 1;
        case 'A' ... 'F':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

// Returns 1 if addr is a valid IPv4 address, otherwise returns 0
int is_ipv4(char *addr) {
    int dots = 0, octets = 0;
    char number[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "0";
    unsigned long len = strlen(addr) + 1; // Length of the string INCLUDING the null terminator
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (addr[i] == '.' || addr[i] == '\0') {
            if (is_digit(addr[i - 1]))
                octets++;
            dots++;
            if (strtol(number, NULL, 10) > 255) {
                return 0;
            }
            strcpy(number, "0");
        }
        strcat(number, &addr[i]);
    }
    if (dots - 1 != 3 || octets != 4) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int is_ipv6(char *addr) {
    int colons = 0, hextets = 0;
    char number[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = "0";
    unsigned long len = strlen(addr) + 1; // Length of the string INCLUDING the null terminator
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (addr[i] == ':' || addr[i] == '\0') {
            if (is_digit(addr[i - 1]))
                hextets++;
            colons++;
            if (strtol(number, NULL, 16) >  65535) { // FFFF (16)
                return 0;
            }
            strcpy(number, "0");
        }
        strcat(number, &addr[i]);
    }
    if (colons - 1 < 2 || colons - 1 > 7) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (colons != 7) {
        if (addr[0] != ':' && addr[strlen(addr) - 1] != ':')
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

/** Returns 1 if addr is a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address, or one of the following error codes
 *  ELONG (-1) -> addr is too long
 *  ECHAR (-2) -> addr contains an invalid character
 *  EINVALID (-3) -> addr is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address
 */
int is_addr(char *addr) {
    int dots = 0, colons = 0;
    unsigned long len = strlen(addr);
    if (len * sizeof(char) >= INET6_ADDRSTRLEN)
        return ELONG;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        // If character is not a digit, colon or dot OR if there are both dots and colons present
        if ((is_digit(addr[i]) == 0 && addr[i] != '.' && addr[i] != ':') || (dots > 0 && colons > 0))
            return ECHAR;

        // Increment dots or colons if character is a dot or a colon
        if (addr[i] == '.')
            dots++;
        else if (addr[i] == ':')
            colons++;
    }
    if (dots > 0) {
        if (is_ipv4(addr)) return 1;
        else return EINVALID;
    } else if (colons > 0)  {
        if (is_ipv6(addr)) return 1;
        else return EINVALID;
    }
}

/** Returns 1 if port is a valid port number, or one of the following error codes
 *  ELONG (-1) -> port is too long
 *  ECHAR (-2) -> port contains an invalid character
 */
int is_port(char *port) {
    unsigned long len = strlen(port);
    if (len > 6)
        return ELONG;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (is_digit(port[i]) == 0)
            return ECHAR;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Returns the address family of a given !VALID! IP address (AF_INET or AF_INET6),
// or -1 in case there is no dot or colon present
int getaddrfamily(char *addr) {
    unsigned long len = strlen(addr);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (addr[i] == '.')
            return AF_INET;
        else if (addr[i] == ':')
            return AF_INET6;
    }
    return -1;
}

// prints the 'usage' message
void printusage() {
    printf("usage:\n./server <addr> <port>\n\n");
    printf("<addr> - IPv4 or IPv6 address for the server to bind to (Enter 0 for list of options)\n");
    printf("<port> - port number for the server to bind to\n");
}

END OF CODE
The other functions should not be importat, just know that strin() takes input from stdin in my case and terminate() free()'s everything that needs to be free()'d
Here is the problem
When I start server.c...
./server 127.0.0.1 8080
getaddrinfo(): Success!
addrstr: 127.0.0.1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Server address: 127.0.0.1
Server port: 8080
socket(): Success!
bind(): Success!
Server listening on port 8080...
Waiting for connection...

It seems to work just fine...
But when I start client.c in the same way...
./client 127.0.0.1 8080
getaddrinfo(): Success!
socket(): Success!
connect(): error: Connection refused

It just says Connection refused
I tried making simple echo server and client (client sends message, receives the same message back) files from scratch to test whether there was a problem on my computer's end (firewall etc.), it worked just fine...
I know I'm asking a lot and there's hundreds of lines of code here, but if anyone has the time and more importantly mood to help me out here I would appreciate it very much!

I tried making a test server.c and client.c files and tried making it from scratch, it worked fine - what does it mean?

There are two possible reasons for "Connection refused". Either there's no server listening on the port, or there's a firewall blocking connections to the port.

@EugeneSh. Sorry, I'll edit the post and explain

So you tested that a server can listen on this port, so you have ruled out the firewall

Looks like your server part listens to on a randomize port (at least I've not spotted out setting it there) and you're trying to connect to some specific port (8080) in the above client part. It's highly unlikely they are the same. [adding something like ipv4->sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2])); will set it there]

@yvs2014 There's this line at the start of server.c that shouldset the port number for all results given by getaddrinfo status = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[2], &hints, &res); Or am I wrong?

it doesn't matter what was before there after resetting address+port with ipv4 = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); inet_pton(AF_INET, addrstr, &ipv4->sin_addr); res->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)ipv4;

It was as @yvs2014 said, I needed to specify ipv4->sin_port = htons(strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10)); (I'm using strtol() instead of atoi() here)
Thank you all very much for trying to help me! I appreciate it very much!
You've allowed me to continue getting better at C!
